# How to convert a paint layer into a fill layer?

Tags: krita

I have a bunch of paint layers that I have drawn on in levels of grey which are coloured by an overlaying colour layer with the "inherit alpha" option turned on.

What I am trying to do is convert all those grey layers into fill layers, but they can't be converted directly (for some reason).

The closest I have come is converting the paint layer to a transparency mask then applying that to a new fill layer, but I would need to find a way to transfer the alpha channel value to white somehow... like an inverted "color to alpha" filter...

Would any of you good people know a way to convert, or copy/paste from a paint layer to a fill layer, or how to transfer alpha channel data to white?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...oh wait, I'm dumb. I misunderstood how fill layers work. Darker values are *supposed* to be transparent, not darker.

Converting the paint layer to a transparency mask and applying it to a new fill layer does exactly what it should.

Hopefully this question will help someone else in the futre...